# Update rejected - Issue: Need login credentials for app review

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I recently updated one of my apps and a few minutes later I got an email saying something like "Issue: Need login credentials for app review". My app is an android client for Shinobi (A CCTV server/software that users install at home). My landing activity in the app is a login page which asks for a server/hostname or ip, a username and a password. Contacted Google support via chat and explained to this to them. Unfortunately all I got was:

> As a general reminder, if we're unable to review your app for compliance (for example, because part of your app is behind a login wall but we don’t have working login credentials), your app may be blocked from releasing new updates or removed from Google Play

I understand that Google requires to test apps before approving but what can I do in this scenario since Google doesn't probably have a Shinobi server installed.

Appreciate any advise.

Comment: i'm not sure what we can do for you here unfortunately, seems like this is between yourself and the support on the store

Comment: @ads I know that in cases of Google email auth, I've seen that you can provide them a mail and password that you created specially for that reason. I don't know what Shinobi is but can you give them a real account details only for logging in? or can you provide that a fake account details and add to your code a case when this account is signed in

Comment: @Avital thanks. i'll consider this as an option.